# Mysql Bulk Update

Tags: mysql, performance, bulkinsert

I have to execute ~6k update queries on a table through sql (No Hibernate/JDBC). Query is something like

```
UPDATE A 
SET 
    some_id = 'value1'
WHERE
    id = 'value2';
```

It takes too long to execute all these queries. Is there a way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 26):

Create a temp table (containing just the value1 and value2 values) and populate it in bulk (ie, you can potentially do this with a single insert statement). Then do an update using a join between your existing table and the temp table.

Something like

```
INSERT INTO SomeTempTable(id, some_id)
VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), .......
```

```
UPDATE A
        INNER JOIN
    SomeTempTable ON A.id = SomeTempTable.id 
SET 
    A.some_id = SomeTempTable.some_id;
```

Comment: how faster this can achieve compared with direct update?

Comment: Quite a bit faster due to needing far less statements sending to the database. If the update is based on a CSV file then potentially the insert could be done using LOAD DATA INFILE.... syntax. If the update is based on a unique key then potentially everything could be done in the INSERT statement using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... syntax.